# jQuery plugin to display the difference between two files in two windows

Tags: jquery

I have 2 test results from the same test plan, they're almost the same with just small differences. Now I would like to display the contents of two test results on the same html page, highlight the differeces, like the effect of `vimdiff`.

I did some research and found `jQuery.PrettyTextDiff` (http://jsfiddle.net/arnab/YwSVY/), it could do some diff works but the format is quite different from my expectation. Could you please introduce some other plugins? Or could I configure `jQuery.PrettyTextDiff` to reach my expectation? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: stackoverflow.com/questions/3053587/javascript-based-diff-utility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might like [this](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib). This is a javascript tool. It produces output similar to vimdiff. See demo [here](http://cemerick.github.io/jsdifflib/demo.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful!